# Mail's attachment encryption via mail-gpg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, sinatra, mandrill

I have to encrypt my email's attachment. I send emails through Mandrill Client(mandrillapp.com).
Gem which I use to encrypt my attachment is mail gpg (https://github.com/jkraemer/mail-gpg)
There aren't errors in console log. And email is coming to me but email/attachment isn't encrypted.
Have you any ideas what's wrong in my app?
My code:

```
def self.mailing(atr1, atr2)
  key = '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)
mQGiBEk39msRBADw1ExmrLD1OUMdfvA7cnVVYTC7CyqfNvHUVuuBDhV7azs ....
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ' 

  mandrill = Mandrill::API.new 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'

  time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  message = {
                from_email: 'test@test.pl',
                subject: "WWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
                to: [{
                  email: App.settings.webservices[atr1]['email'],
                  type: "to"
                  },
                  {
                  email: App.settings.webservices[atr1]['email_bcc'],
                  type: "bcc"
                  }
                  ],
                attachments: [{
                    content: Base64.encode64(build_csv(atr2)),
                    name: "my_name" ,
                    type: 'text/csv',
                    gpg: { encrypt: true }# , keys: { App.settings.webservices['ggggg']['email'] => key} }
                  }],
                  # gpg: { encrypt: true, keys: { App.settings.webservices['ggggg']['email_bcc']} }
                }
  result = mandrill.messages.send message
  result.first.with_indifferent_access   
end
```

Thank you for Help

Comment: You only want to encrypt attachment and not the whole mail?

Comment: Which gem *exactly*? Mandrill say to use the Mailchimp gem.

Comment: The gem which I use is called 'mandrill-api'. I tried to encrypt whole email also but result is the same. The encryption didn't work by mail-gpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail-gpg extends the Mail gem so it can send Pgp/Mime encrypted messages.

Encrypting just an attachment is not supported. Either encrypt the whole message [as documented](http://github.com/jkraemer/mail-gpg) or encrypt the attachment manually (i.e using the gpgme gem) before attaching it to your email.

So if at all, pass the gpg option at the message (top) level of the hash to the Mandrill gem (provided it somehow does the right thing then, which I don't know). If that fails, build your Mail::Message yourself and send it via Mandrill's Smtp servers. You don't need their gem for that.

Comment: As you see under attachment I tried to encrypt whole mail but it didn't work and I was surprised becouse I've done everything what is in documentation but my messages coming into gmail weren't encrypted.
I try to encrypt it by gpgme as you said.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code how you try to do what's documented - you just build a Hash and hand that to the mandrill library. I guess this library simply does not know anything about mail-gpg and just ignores your `gpg` hash keys, wherever you put them. The easy way around this would be, as I wrote before, to use the Mail gem API and send your emails via SMTP.

Comment: I will use gpgme gem to encrypt it from outside as you said. I thought that mail-gem will work with mandrill becouse mandrill use ActionMailer as I know. 
Thank you for help!!